IEEE Floating-Point Number Bound for (b-a)+a, where 0=<a<=b
It is a specific niche question, hence stated fully in the title:
Question
Given two non-negative numbers a and b, where a is less or equal to b, I care in whether y as per the following algorithm is less or equal to b.
Algorithm:
x = b-a;
y = x+a;

Is y<=b in general so long as 0<=a<=b ?
Remarks

I would expect these properties are well-analyzed, yet Wikipedia and GPT are clueless.
Who has a couple of good references?
I further do not only care in float and double. I care in any IEEE-compliant number.


The reference for this would be the classic "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic". Theorem 5 looks like what you are looking for

The single precision number space is small enough to experiment with every possible value for b and some guesses for a. We can expect issues either with a being close to zero or close to b. With default rounding mode you will not get any failures but if the rounding mode is changed to positive infinity, it does fail. See https://pastebin.com/t9ixDuY1 for test code

This is clearly false when rounding upward is used. (For a tiny non-zero a, x = b-a produces b, but y = x+a produces the next representable value greater than b.) Do you mean to ask for round-to-nearest, ties-to-even?

@Homer512: Theorem 5 says that, for round-to-nearest, ties-to-even, x-y+y-y+y-y+y…-y+y yields the same value as x-y+y, which may or may not equal x. It is silent about the question asked here, whether x-y+y must be less than or equal to x given that 0 ≤ y ≤ x.

Notation
a and b are the values of a and b, respectively, and similarly for x and y. b− is the next value representable in the floating-point format less than b, and b+ is the next value representable that is greater than b.
Mathematics in plain font represents real-number mathematics. b−a is the unrounded real-number result of subtraction. Mathematics in code font represents floating-point operations. b-a is the result of performing floating-point subtraction, equal to b−a rounded to a representable value according to a selected rounding method.
False With Round Upward
y ≤ b is clearly false if round upward (round toward +∞) is used:
Let b be 1 and a be ½(b−b−). (I assume the exponent range of the format suffices to represent a.) Then b−a is not representable and is between b− and b. With rounding upward, x = b-a produces b. Then x+a is between b and b+, so, with rounding upward, y = x+a produces b+. This violates y ≤ b.
True With Round Downward or Toward Zero
With round downward (toward −∞) or toward zero, we consider two cases: a is zero, and a is not zero (0 < a ≤ b).
With a = 0, x = b-a produces b, and y = x+a produces b, and y ≤ b is satisfied.
With a not zero, x = b-a produces some value less than or equal to b−a, due to the rounding direction. Then y = x+a produces some value less than or equal to x+a ≤ b−a+a = b, so y ≤ b holds.
False With Round To Nearest
Using IEEE-754 binary32 for float with round-to-nearest, ties-to-even, this code produces a y greater than b:
float b = 0x.FFFFFFp0;
float a = 0x.0000018p0;
float x = b-a;
float y = x+a;

Explanation: Let b be 1−2−24. (This is the representable value immediately preceding 1, equal to 0.FFFFFF16.) Let a be 1½•2−24 (equivalently 1.5•2−24, 3•2−25, or 0.000001816).
b−a = 1−2−24 − 3•2−25 = 1-5•2−25 = 0.FFFFFD816, which is not representable in binary32. (In binary, its leading 1 bit is at 2−1, and its trailing 1 bit is at 2−25, which span more than the 24 bits in the significand of the binary32 format.) It is halfway between the adjacent representable values 1−3•2−24 = 0.FFFFFD16 and 1−2•2−24 = 0.FFFFFE16. Since these are equidistant, rounding using round-to-nearest, ties-to-even produces the one with the even low digit, 0.FFFFFE16 = 1−2•2−24. So x = b-a sets x to this value.
Now consider y = x+a. x+@a is 1−2•2−24 + 3•2−25 = 1−2•2−25 = 0.FFFFFF816. This is not representable. It is midway between the adjacent representable values 1−2−24 = 0.FFFFFF16 and 1 = 1.0000016. Again, the one with the even low digit is used, so y = x+a produces 1. Since y is 1 and b is 1−2−24, y ≤ b is false.

Thank you a lot. So there is no hope on any front with this :D
